# Working with instance variables within a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to instantiate a "Battle" upon creation with some variables that I can manipulate without accessing the database and then first when all the method calls and calculation has been done, save the battle result to the database. I want the "player" method to return the sorted array that was created in the callback, but at the moment it just returns nil

```
class Battle < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create do
      @battlelog = ""
      @field = []
      @conditions = []
      @player = sort_by_initiative(action.character.army.members.map{ |m| [m.unit, m.amount]})      
        @computer = sort_by_initiative(action.instance.members.map{ |m| [m.unit, m.amount]})
    end

    # Associations
    belongs_to :action

    def sort_by_initiative(array)
        array.sort { |a, b| b.first.initiative <=> a.first.initiative }
    end

    def player
        @player
    end
```

Comment: Try adding `attr_accessible :player` in the Battle model

Comment: don't think so, attr is deprecated in rails 4 and yields an error "RuntimeError: `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.
"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `attr_accessor :player`, (this is Ruby, see Ruby classes for more) which creates an accessible attribute (read and write) on the model instance. `attr_reader :player` would give you a read-only attribute, which is used if the attribute is set by internal operations. You can then call `this_battle.player` on `this_battle` as an instance of the class `Battle`. Remember though that these attributes will usually not persist if you call other controller actions or render new views unless you have a way to store them permanently.